# force select2-plugin to show all items

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) and would like to force it show all available options when expanded instead of adding a scrollbar.

Right now it has a scrollbar inside the option area: http://screencast.com/t/fYKPArqz5f

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the CSS in select2.css, roughly line 302:

```css
/* results */
.select2-results {
    /* max-height: 200px;  comment out the max-height! */
    padding: 0 0 0 4px;
    margin: 4px 4px 4px 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Or if you don't have access to the CSS, or don't want to change it generally across your site, you can override the specific style in your own stylesheet:

```css
.select2-results {
    max-height: none;
}
```

See this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/979nG/7/)